# Google Docs Spreadsheet Info for Finance stocks

Tags: google-docs, finance, stocks

Im trying to have dividend payable dates, or ex-dividend dates populate in the cell next to a ticker.  Anyone ever done this?  Does not seem I can find this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to find a web page that provides this information based on a given ticker, you can use *importXml* function in the spreadsheet.

This function gets the URL of the site (probably with some query as q=TICKER), and XPATH expression of the field with the relevant value.

You can find the XPATH using "Inspect Elemnt" in Chrome, Safari and other modern browsers.